# Find fractions strictly not preceded by certain characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to find fractions not preceded by a word followed by a /, for example, s2. My  code doesn't work for that one but it's able to capture for other ones. Can you please help modify the regex expression? The expected is given followed by _f.

```
s2="Virus/02/2013"
s3="Helium Nitrogen 10/10"
s4="Nitrogen Oxygen10/20"
s5="glycol,water,oxygen, 10/20/30"
concat=c(s2,s3,s4,s5)
stringr::str_replace_all(concat,"(?<!\\/)(?<!\\/)\\d*\\.?\\d+(\\s+)?\\/\\d*\\.?\\d+(\\s+)?(\\/\\d*\\.?\\d+(\\s+)?)?","")

s2_f="Virus/02/2013"
s3_f="Helium Nitrogen"
s4_f="Nitrogen Oxygen"
s5_f="glycol,water,oxygen"
```

Comment: Yes it is @akrun, I was converting b/c this is a part of the regex but I removed it for now

Comment: It took me a while, but I think you're saying you want e.g. `s2` to be converted to `s2_f`. So you want to eliminate all fractions, except those that come immediately after e.g. "Virus/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could match either a regex lookaround to match the lower case letters (`(?<=[a-z])`) followed by either one or more space, comma (`[, ]+`) followed by any `/` and digits (`\\d+`) and other characters (`.*`) or (`|`) one or more digits and other characters and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("(?<=[a-z])(([, ]+\\/?\\d+.*)|(\\d+.*))", "", concat, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "Virus/02/2013"       "Helium Nitrogen"   
[3] "Nitrogen Oxygen"     "glycol,water,oxygen"
```